# Following CNAME alias causes different HTML rendering

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, cname-record

I am running Windows Server 2012 with Apache and ColdFusion 11.

In our DNS manager on our local domain, we have set up a CNAME alias that points to our reporting server. When you access the the server by it's non aliased name (e.g. myserver.example.com) it works fine. But when using the CNAME (reporting.example.com), there are formatting issues. The fonts are not correct and images don't display correctly.

I'm not very knowledgeable on DNS and domains in general, so any help is appreciated. I can provide more info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Contact the web application developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. We had to add the alias name to the server's hosts file.

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly caused by something in your application, or web server configuration that is dependent on the hostname.  You should talk to the system administrator and/or developer in charge of those things.  Things to look for:

- Absolute links that could be causing XSS errors when accessed through an alternate domain name
- Use of any of the various hostname variables
- Any NamedVirtualHosts in your apache config